# Manipulating Uniswap V2's pair totalSupply via flash loan

Tags: uniswap, liquidity-provider, flash-loans, math, uniswapv2

Let's assume that I'm writing a UniswapV2 LP token price oracle. Would it be a bad idea to rely on the LP token totalSupply for my calculation? Would it be possible to manipulate its value through a flash loan attack?

I'm mainly asking this question as I'm currently researching Alpha Finance's code for their LP token price oracle. They introduce the concept of [fair reserves](https://blog.alphaventuredao.io/fair-lp-token-pricing) through the following formula:

[image]

Which could be simplified as follows:

[image]

`p0` and `p1` could be made flashloan-proof, as they could be pulled from Chainlink or Uniswap's TWAP price oracles. But I'm not sure if a flash loan attacker would be able to manipulate the total supply of the LP token (`L`), or even `k` for that matter. Or if it's simply the case that in case of a flash loan attack, both `L` and `k` would change and both changes would cancel out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider the case where a flash loan attacker would try to manipulate the `totalSupply` by deposition tokens to the pool.

The new LP token `totalSupply` would be:

[image]

From equation (12) in the Uniswap V2 whitepaper, the change in the LP token supply is described by:

[image]

Which leads to:

[image]

The new constant product (`k`) would be:

[image]

By substituting in the fair reserve formula, we get:

[image]

Meaning, the price of the LP token does not change when new LP tokens are minted. A similar proof could be derived for when liquidity tokens are burned from the pool, but with the only difference being the term in nominator and denominator being eliminated.